# Receiving a Cannot POST error when attempting to post data in a rest client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am receiving this error when attempting to post a new entry into a database I have created, called Doctors.

My server.js looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const morgan = require('morgan');
var Doctor = require('./www/js/user.js');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('www'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app';
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database:' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});

app.post('/doctors', function (req, res) {
    var doctor = new Doctor();
    doctor.doctorID = req.body.doctorID;
    doctor.password = req.body.password;
    doctor.save();
    res.send('doctor created');
});

// Configure port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Listen to port
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./www/index.html');
});
```

My user.js, which is my schema, looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var DoctorSchema = new Schema({
    doctorID: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

//encrypt password
DoctorSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var doctor = this;
    bcrypt.hash(doctor.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
        if (err) return next(err);
        doctor.password = hash;
        next();
    });
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Doctor', DoctorSchema);
```

When attempting to post, I get this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /doctors</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this particular error. I can get data from /doctors with no issues, I just can't post to it.

Comment: This may be because you are using `"*"` for `app.get` below `app.post`.. what happens if you move `app.post` below `app.get("*", ...)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the exact same thing. Still a Cannot POST error.

Comment: The "*" bit wont be hit anyway as its been placed after the .listen call. Anything after .listen will never be hit.

Comment: @kickergold can you supply the code you are using to send the `POST` request?

Comment: I suspect its because hes using app.post() but hes also setup const router = express.Router()

Comment: I'm sending it in ARC in the standard POST request. I'm sending
{
  "doctorID": "6",
  "password": "password"
}
and I'm sending it to http://localhost:8080/doctors

Comment: Can you please try the example I provided in the answers...

Answer (score 0):

Please change your server.js to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const morgan = require('morgan');
var Doctor = require('./www/js/user.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('www'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app';
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database:' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});

app.post('/doctors', function (req, res) {
    var doctor = new Doctor();
    doctor.doctorID = req.body.doctorID;
    doctor.password = req.body.password;
    doctor.save();
    res.send('doctor created');
});

// Configure port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./www/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(
    `Server listening on port ${port}!`
  );
});
```

**EDIT** - Just correcting an issue in the .listen

Comment: Actually, I just tested this - this is incorrect.  While having a route below `listen` it still works just fine.

Comment: I tried it, and unfortunately nothing changed. Still the same error. Don't know if that means my error isn't to do with the server.js.

Comment: Easiest way to test this would be to change your app.post('/doctors') and just have res.send('POST') within it. If the route itself is working, you'll get 'POST' as a response. Then we know the route itself is correct. If that works, the issue is witin your Doctors

Comment: Also, doctor can still be const not var.

Comment: Tried that, the error is still the same. Apparently not an issue specifically with the doctors code.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot POST /doctors in express means that a particular route doesn't exist.

Can you show more code, on what port are you posting ?

Comment: I'm attempting to POST on http://localhost:8080/doctors, and sending {
  "doctorID": "6",
  "password": "password"
}.

Comment: Does localhost:8080 returns the html page ?

Comment: Yes, it does return that

Comment: @kickergold oh sorry man I didn't saw this, can you try changing * with /* in get route. And put that route above /doctors .

Comment: Tried that, exactly the same problem :/ no idea what is causing this now!

Comment: I tried your code and it works okey without mongoose. Can you just try another port,  your code seems fine.

Comment: Changed the port to 8000, same request. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the right content type in the request?

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Else, the `req.body.doctorID` will return `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, I've set it to that. Sadly not the problem.

Comment: I have commented the MongoDB section and I was able to see the proper response ; without making any other changes to your code. Did you try debugging that way?

Comment: Do you mean this part?
const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/votee';
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database:' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});

Comment: I was just trying to see if Express is working fine, by commenting MongoDB related code. I just returned the doctorID from the POST function and it worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this successfully.. It appears the issue is with your `Mongo` code..

Try this, if it works, you know the issue is with the `Mongo` section.

This is how I am sending the requests.. using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

[image]

This shows how I am able to receive the request:

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
//const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
//const morgan = require('morgan');
//var Doctor = require('./www/js/user.js');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('www'));
//app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app';
/*
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database:' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});
*/

app.post('/doctors', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send();
    /*
    var doctor = new Doctor();
    doctor.doctorID = req.body.doctorID;
    doctor.password = req.body.password;
    doctor.save();
    res.send('doctor created');
    */
});

// Configure port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Listen to port
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./www/index.html');
});
```

To expand on this answer.. I usually configure `Mongoose` in the following manner..

Folder Structure:

```
root
 |- database
   |- index.js
 |- models
   |- someModel.js
```

In `/root/database/index.js`:

```
'use strict'
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoBaseUrl = `mongodb://server:27017/collection`;
const mongoDB      = mongoose.createConnection(mongoBaseUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, promiseLibrary: global.Promise });

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true) // needed to suppress errors
module.exports = mongoDB;
```

Then in `/root/models/someModel.js`:

```
'use strict'
const mongoose        = require('mongoose');
const mongoConnection = require('../database');

const modelName       = "SomeModel";
const collection      = "SomeCollection";
const databaseName    = "SomeDatabase";

const myDatabase      = mongoConnection.useDb(databaseName);


const SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Schema data here
})


module.exports = myDatabase.model(modelName, SomeSchema, collection) // (database, schema, collection)
```

Then to use it in your routes:

```
const Doctor = require('./models/someModel.js');
app.post('/route/', (req, res, next) => {
    var doctor = new Doctor();
    doctor.doctorID = req.body.doctorID;
    doctor.password = req.body.password;
    doctor.save();
    res.send('doctor created');
});
```

Something to that effect.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That change is not working on my end. What do you think that would point towards?

Comment: How are you actually posting the data?

Comment: You will need to show us the code you are using the actually send the POST request.  I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send the request. I have uploaded pictures of how I am sending the request to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the issue was with neither, we had a duplicated server.js, and it was referencing the incorrect one. Thanks for the help anyway! Hope this thread helps someone else.

Comment: I upvoted them, dunno what you're talking about. I have low rep so it doesn't show up :/

Comment: Two of the same Express servers? I don't think this post is helpful at all and should be closed as non-reproducible.